# Why my react-native app is crashing in XCode Build?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

After a lot of work I was able to build my app for ios, but after it succeeds building the app crashes and some logs appear in the xcode:

```
2020-02-16 23:01:58.268 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:213] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7f899241ec10> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x600000188770>, executor: (null))
2020-02-16 23:01:58.418 [warn][tid:main][RCTModuleData.mm:67] Module RNFetchBlob requires main queue setup since it overrides `constantsToExport` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2020-02-16 23:01:58.429 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:213] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7f899260ff00> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000001ae7d0>, executor: (null))
2020-02-16 23:01:58.431 [warn][tid:main][RCTModuleData.mm:67] Module RNFetchBlob requires main queue setup since it overrides `constantsToExport` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2020-02-16 23:01:58.537 [warn][tid:NSOperationQueue 0x7f89925157c0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)][RCTModuleData.mm:248] RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RCTDevLoadingView. This may lead to deadlocks
2020-02-16 23:01:58.656 [warn][tid:NSOperationQueue 0x7f89926135a0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)][RCTModuleData.mm:248] RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RCTDevLoadingView. This may lead to deadlocks
2020-02-16 23:01:59.275 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.277 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/Interstitial.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.277 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.278 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/RewardedVideo.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.279 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/Interstitial.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.281 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/RewardedVideo.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/admob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.285 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/SyncTree.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.287 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/SyncTree.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/Reference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.288 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.289 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/database/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.290 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.290 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/Query.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/QuerySnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentChange.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.291 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.291 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/FieldValue.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.292 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.292 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/Query.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/QuerySnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentChange.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/CollectionReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.292 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/DocumentReference.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.293 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/FieldValue.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/utils/serialize.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.293 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/functions/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.295 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/utils/apps.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/app.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/functions/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/core/firebase.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.300 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/task.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-02-16 23:01:59.303 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Require cycle: node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/reference.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/task.js -> node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/storage/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

[The XCode goes to this file (string.h) and gives this error too, 'com.facebook.react.JavaScript (13): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcNJI.png)

I just want to know if anyone has any idea of what the error could be. I don't even need a solution, just to know why the app is crashing.

Comment: Have you created any custom ios module? its seems when you trying to connect your app with this native module using rctbridge you're getting issue.

Comment: I linked an entire firebase folder manually

Comment: Why just use react-native link command for the same.

Comment: I got some problems doing the regular linking so I had to do it manually following this https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1847#issuecomment-457952828